# SQL - Bulk Insert and Data Types

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Today I have a bulk insert from fixed width file like this:

```
BULK INSERT #TBF8DPR501
FROM 'C:\File.txt' WITH (
        FORMATFILE = 'C:\File.txt.xml'
        ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
        )
```

The format file is just to set the width of each field, and after the bulk insert into the temp table, I crated an `INSERT INTO X SELECT FROM temp` to convert some columns that the bulk cannot convert.

My question is, is it possible to make the bulk insert be able to convert values such as:

- Date in format `dd.MM.yyyy` OR `ddMMyyyy`
- Decimal values like this `0000000000010022` (where it is `100.22`)

Without the need to make the bulk insert into a temp table to convert the values?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't: `BULK INSERT` simply copies data as fast as possible, it doesn't transform the data in any way. Your current solution with a temp table is a very common one used in data warehousing and reporting scenarios, so if it works the way you want I would just keep using it.

If you do want to do the transformation during the load, then you could use an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool such as [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services). But there is nothing wrong with your current approach and SSIS would be a very 'heavy' alternative.

Comment: My only "problem" is that right now it takes 4 hours to run (txt with 30gb), im trying to decrease this value staying only inside sql server, there is nothing else that can be done within sql? Thanks

Comment: Why did you ask about formatting data if your real issue is performance? Have you read and followed the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx) on optimizing bulk operations?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried most optimizations (bulk logged / lock / etc), but the speed would not improve.. so far what i managed to do was to use the openrowset with the bulk option.. that way i managed to remove the temp table and insert the data as it reads. I managed to bring down the time to 3 hours.. not sure if there is anything else i could do

Comment: That's old post, and i'm searching stuff. But considering 30GB of data in 4hr as long? :D It's 10 years later and i still would consider that acceptable :D